# Livepatch - Does This Even Do Anything?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, kernel, updates, canonical-livepatch

So, I installed LivePatch on 2 machines. One of them Ubuntu 20.04.2 and the other 18.04.5. New kernel versions came with security fixes. LivePatch did not do anything. I had to install the new kernel updates and still reboot. What am I missing here? Does LivePatch even do anything? I don't think so...

Comment: Did you follow everything on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch ?

Comment: Installed and added keys. Will check, if there is anything else to add. Have a firewall. Maybe it is preventing it from doing anything. I also tried manually checking for updates through it. It does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Check your kernel versions. Livepatch supports only GA kernels (the ones that are the official ones at the LTS release). If you manually update the kernel, you may end in a different (newer) version that is not supported.

Check versions here:
https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/kernels

Comment: This is annoying/inconvenient for those of us who, for instance, install the HWE stack.   I should probably write a question about whether the livepatch devs plan to add support for HWE kernels from the repositories.

Comment: Just an update for new visitors. This is no longer an issue since now Kernel Livepatch supports HWE kernels: https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-livepatch-gets-even-better-now-supporting-hardware-enablement-kernels