# Why does my livepatch never get any patches?

Tags: canonical-livepatch

This may be a duplicate of
[Livepatch - Does This Even Do Anything?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325758/livepatch-does-this-even-do-anything)
I have livepatch supposedly running on two machines, one with 18.04.5 LTS 4.15.0-147-generic and one with 20.04.2 LTS 5.8.0-55-generic.  I installed it a while ago using the free for personal use system.  As I recall at one time it was able to install patches.  However, it now always says that I am up to date without ever installing anything.  E.g.,

```
# canonical-livepatch status
last check: 3 seconds ago
kernel: 5.8.0-55.62~20.04.1-generic
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: no livepatches needed for this kernel yet
```

But it is not true that no patches are needed.  There was just a security announcement saying that there was a patch for CVE-2021-3609 applying to this release.

Comment: Seems obvious but you've checked that >Software & Updates>Livepatch is set to on? Can you ping Canonical?

Comment: Yes, @ThompsonDawes, Software & Updates>Livepatch is set to on.  See above: livepatch claims that it has succeeded in connecting to the server, but no patches are needed.